What is "real men"?
Here is the quote from "A more beautiful question" by Warren Berger

The genesis of many great start-ups is the simple question "Wouldn’t it be cool if?" W. helps you understand the power of questions to change the world. Real men ask questions, they don’t spout out answers.

I want to know "Real men" in this sentence mean? Men is a man (human), or male (in male/female)

It is an opinion by the narrator of that story. You need to provide a link or a title of the book.

"A more beautiful question" by Warren Berger

It is a value judgment. real men as opposed to cowards, pussies, lightweights, "boys", etc.

that's basically all an answer needs, Lambie

@JamesK Yes, but Peter has a good one too.

"Real men" is a phrase commonly used to discuss characteristics of masculinity. As such it is gender specific: it refers to males only.
Depending on context it may be used both seriously and humorously. A popular example from a few years ago was a book entitled "Real men Don't Eat Quiche". The book was a commentary on and criticism of social gender stereotypes: In order to be a real man you need to eat steak and hot dogs. You need to hide your emotions. You need to talk about football and fast cars. And so on.
In the OP example, apparently a "real man" will ask the right questions that inspire new and creative business ideas. He won't just spout out the ideas about the world that others before him have given.
